# Get a list of custom classes in Python?

Tags: python

Is there a way to get a list of classes defined by the user only?

So far I am able to display a list of all classes in a module with the following:

```
inspect.getmembers(sys.modules[__name__])
```

The problem is that I get a list special methods and other stuff.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Finally I did it this way:**

```
from folder1 import module_name as mod

for name, cls in mod.__dict__.items():
                if isinstance(cls, type):
                    klass = getattr(mod, name)
```

Comment: I would replace `for name, cls in mod.__dict__.items():` with `for name in dir(mod):` `cls = getattr(mod, name)`. And as it is, you can be certain that `klass is cls`, so that line is wasted.